# PureScript. Argument list lengths differ in declaration

Tags: purescript

```
import Prelude

data Line = Front | Middle | Back

derive instance eqLine :: Eq Line

instance ordLine :: Ord Line where
  compare a b | a == b = EQ
  compare Front _ = LT
  compare Back _ = GT
  compare = flip compare
```

Why does this give me the error 'Argument list lengths differ in declaration compare'.
But if I change the last line to

```
compare a b = flip compare a b
```

then it compiles.

I thought `flip compare` returns a function of 2 args hence matches signature of `compare`, but apparently it doesn't. 
Repl:

```
> :type flip compare
forall (t4 :: Type). Ord t4 => t4 -> t4 -> Ordering
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a syntax requirement. If you provide several equations for a function, they all have to have the same number of arguments. Syntactically, not logically.

This is required as a confusion-reducing measure. Just so that whoever is reading your program months later can see what's going on clearer.